# Running Gitlab on Apache2 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) : Assets not loading

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

I am currently setting up Gitlab on my Ubuntu Server 14.04. After installing Gitlab, disabling Nginx and settings a virtual host for apache2 the interface actually loads - but one of the asset files (the main Javascript file) throws an proxy error and returns a 502 Status.

The error.log says:

```
[Tue Jan 27 14:25:10.198423 2015] [proxy_http:error] [pid 26941] (20014)Internal error: [client 155.56.40.102:60125] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution for my setup. The Unicorn server of Gitlab was default set to port 8080 - which I think somehow collided with the apache2 configuration. After setting Unicorn's port to 8000 and adapting the port in apaches's site-available for Gitlab, apache's virtual host worked fine and the script was successfully loaded in the Gitlab start page.

Hope that is helpful in case anyone faces the same problem.